# SwiftUI: ObservableObject does not persist its State over being redrawn

Tags: swift, swiftui, declarative, property-wrapper

## Problem

In Order to achieve a clean look and feel of the App's code, I create ViewModels for every View that contains logic.

A normal ViewModel looks a bit like this:

```
class SomeViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var state = 1

    // Logic and calls of Business Logic goes here
}
```

and is used like so:

```
struct SomeView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel = SomeViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        // Code to read and write the State goes here
    }
}
```

This workes fine when the Views Parent is not being updated. If the parent's state changes, this View gets redrawn (pretty normal in a declarative Framework). **But** also the ViewModel gets recreated and does not hold the State afterward. This is unusual when you compare to other Frameworks (eg: Flutter).

*In my opinion, the ViewModel should stay, or the State should persist.*

If I replace the ViewModel with a `@State` Property and use the `int` (in this example) directly it stays persisted and **does not get recreated**:

```
struct SomeView: View {

    @State var state = 1

    var body: some View {
        // Code to read and write the State goes here
    }
}
```

This does obviously not work for more complex States. And if I set a class for `@State` (like the ViewModel) more and more Things are not working as expected.

## Question

- Is there a way of not recreating the ViewModel every time?
- Is there a way of replicating the `@State` Propertywrapper for `@ObservedObject`?
- Why is @State keeping the State over the redraw?

I know that usually, it is bad practice to create a ViewModel in an inner View but this behavior can be replicated by using a NavigationLink or Sheet.
Sometimes it is then just not useful to keep the State in the ParentsViewModel and work with bindings when you think of a very complex TableView, where the Cells themself contain a lot of logic.
There is always a workaround for individual cases, but I think it would be way easier if the ViewModel would not be recreated.

## Duplicate Question

I know there are a lot of questions out there talking about this issue, all talking about very specific use-cases. Here I want to talk about the general problem, without going too deep into custom solutions.

## Edit (adding more detailed Example)

When having a State-changing ParentView, like a list coming from a Database, API, or cache (think about something simple). Via a `NavigationLink` you might reach a Detail-Page where you can modify the Data. By changing the data the reactive/declarative Pattern would tell us to also update the ListView, which would then "redraw" the `NavigationLink`, which would then lead to a recreation of the ViewModel.

I know I could store the ViewModel in the ParentView / ParentView's ViewModel, but this is the wrong way of doing it IMO. And since subscriptions are destroyed and/or recreated - there might be some side effects.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? I ended up creating an environmentObject so it only has one instance of the view model.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Finally, there is a Solution provided by Apple: `@StateObject`.

By replacing `@ObservedObject` with `@StateObject` everything mentioned in my initial post is working.

Unfortunately, this is only available in ios 14+.

This is my Code from Xcode 12 Beta (Published June 23, 2020)

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var title = 0

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button("Test") {
                    self.title = Int.random(in: 0...1000)
                }

                TestView1()

                TestView2()
            }
            .navigationTitle("\(self.title)")
        }
    }
}

struct TestView1: View {

    @ObservedObject var model = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Test1: \(self.model.title)") {
                self.model.title += 1
            }
        }
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var title = 0
}

struct TestView2: View {

    @StateObject var model = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("StateObject: \(self.model.title)") {
                self.model.title += 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `StateObject` Keeps it value upon the redraw of the Parent View, while the `ObservedObject` is being reset.

Comment: Hello! I was wondering if you found any solution for iOS 13? I really need to fix this issue and whatever I tried did not work sadly.

Comment: @AbdulelahHajjar, I think the only way would be to create the ViewModel way down in your View Hierarchy. It can be tricky at some points. Or update to 14+, this would be the most easiest solution

Comment: Thanks @KonDeichmann for you response, could you please elaborate as what it means to "create the ViewModel way down in the view hierarchy"? Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: @AbdulelahHajjar, already create the ViewModel in the Parent View (or the View that changes the State). This sometimes not workes when you have to pass data into that ViewModel. I would probably suggest updating your deployment Target then.

Comment: what if the `StateObject` takes parameters in its `init`, like: `MyViewModel(status: 2)`, giving that we have to create this view model from outside the View, how can I make the view preserve its state in this case ? Apple discourages passing `StateObject` from outside the View in contrast to `ObservableObjects` but those don't preserve the state on View redrawing.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with you, I think this is one of many major problems with SwiftUI. Here's what I find myself doing, as gross as it is.

```
struct MyView: View {
  @State var viewModel = MyViewModel()

  var body : some View {
    MyViewImpl(viewModel: viewModel)
  }
}

fileprivate MyViewImpl : View {
  @ObservedObject var viewModel : MyViewModel

  var body : some View {
    ...
  }
}
```

You can either construct the view model in place or pass it in, and it gets you a view that will maintain your ObservableObject across reconstruction.

Comment: Hey, you are completely right. I think I mentioned this solution in my question as well. The problem is that the Parent View of `MyView` could be redrawn and we would end up with the same problem.

But indeed I currently implement Solutions this way. But as a very general approach, there are problems too.

Comment: @KonDeichmann, I don't think that should be true. If a parent struct is modified, all child structs have to be copied/recreated, but any `@State` within those should be maintained in separate storage and restored after the child view struct init(). This "wrapper" pattern is the equivalent of writing `@State @ObservedObject var viewModel : MyViewModel`. It prevents your view model from being lost on redraw. The parent only references `MyView`, which is a wrapper that maintains state for `MyViewImpl`.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way of not recreating the ViewModel every time?

Yes, keep ViewModel instance **outside** of `SomeView` and inject via constructor

```
struct SomeView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: SomeViewModel  // << only declaration
```

> Is there a way of replicating the @State Propertywrapper for @ObservedObject?

No needs. `@ObservedObject` is-a already `DynamicProperty` similarly to `@State`

> Why is @State keeping the State over the redraw?

Because it keeps its storage, ie. wrapped value, **outside** of view. (so, see first above again)

Comment: sometimes you don't need to redraw (init) whole view every time something changes. In my case there was heavy shape calculations in init, which I didn't want to execute every time something changes. Especially when you have "state" singleton. You changes one property - all the views depending on state redrawn. Even if they depends on another property. I think topic starter dealing with similar problem.

Comment: Keeping the State outside of the View is a Solution indeed, but in some cases, it is not practical! Think about a complex Detail Page, where you make changes to the Object, that then updates the List of Items on the Parent View (State change).
Also, in this case, the '@State' property keeps it State, the '@ObservedObject' does not.

Comment: @KonDeichmann, it does - used widely, and here on SO... moreover combined solution with both is also possible.

Comment: But a combined Solution (a combination of @State, which persists, and @ObservedObject) could not keep subscriptions over the redraw. Sure I could "store" a certain State in the View (which is not a good practice, when the state should have been hidden in the ViewModel), but definitely not a Subscription.

Comment: Hello! I tried this solution with no luck, sadly. I was wondering if I did anything wrong on my part. I have the declaration inside the view, and I am passing the ViewModel in the View call from the parent view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide custom `PassThroughSubject` in your `ObservableObject` class. Look at this code:

```
//
//  Created by Франчук Андрей on 08.05.2020.
//  Copyright © 2020 Франчук Андрей. All rights reserved.
//

import SwiftUI
import Combine


struct TextChanger{
    var textChanged = PassthroughSubject<String,Never>()
    public func changeText(newValue: String){
        textChanged.send(newValue)
    }
}

class ComplexState: ObservableObject{
    var objectWillChange = ObservableObjectPublisher()
    let textChangeListener = TextChanger()
    var text: String = ""
    {
        willSet{
            objectWillChange.send()
            self.textChangeListener.changeText(newValue: newValue)
        }
    }
}

struct CustomState: View {
    @State private var text: String = ""
    let textChangeListener: TextChanger
    init(textChangeListener: TextChanger){
        self.textChangeListener = textChangeListener
        print("did init")
    }
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .onReceive(textChangeListener.textChanged){newValue in
                self.text = newValue
            }
    }
}
struct CustomStateContainer: View {
    //@ObservedObject var state = ComplexState()
    var state = ComplexState()
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Text("custom state View: ")
                CustomState(textChangeListener: state.textChangeListener)
            }
            HStack{
                Text("ordinary Text View: ")
                Text(state.text)
            }
            HStack{
                Text("text input: ")
                TextInput().environmentObject(state)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TextInput: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var state: ComplexState
    var body: some View {
        TextField("input", text: $state.text)
    }
}

struct CustomState_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        return CustomStateContainer()
    }
}
```

First, I using `TextChanger` to pass new value of `.text` to `.onReceive(...)` in `CustomState` View. Note, that `onReceive` in this case gets `PassthroughSubject`, not the `ObservableObjectPublisher`. In last case you will have only `Publisher.Output` in `perform: closure`, not the NewValue. `state.text` in that case would have old value.

Second, look at the `ComplexState` class. I made an `objectWillChange` property to make text changes send notification to subscribers manually. Its almost the same like `@Published` wrapper do. But, when the text changing it will send both, and `objectWillChange.send()` and `textChanged.send(newValue)`. This makes you be able to choose in exact `View`, how to react on state changing. If you want ordinary behavior, just put the state into `@ObservedObject` wrapper in `CustomStateContainer` View. Then, you will have all the views recreated and this section will get updated values too:

```
HStack{
     Text("ordinary Text View: ")
     Text(state.text)
}
```

If you don't want all of them to be recreated, just remove @ObservedObject.  Ordinary text View will stop updating, but CustomState will. With no recreating.

update:
If you want more control, you can decide while changing the value, who do you want to inform about that change.
Check more complex code:

```
//
//
//  Created by Франчук Андрей on 08.05.2020.
//  Copyright © 2020 Франчук Андрей. All rights reserved.
//

import SwiftUI
import Combine


struct TextChanger{
//    var objectWillChange: ObservableObjectPublisher
   // @Published
    var textChanged = PassthroughSubject<String,Never>()
    public func changeText(newValue: String){
        textChanged.send(newValue)
    }
}

class ComplexState: ObservableObject{
    var onlyPassthroughSend = false
    var objectWillChange = ObservableObjectPublisher()
    let textChangeListener = TextChanger()
    var text: String = ""
    {
        willSet{
            if !onlyPassthroughSend{
                objectWillChange.send()
            }
            self.textChangeListener.changeText(newValue: newValue)
        }
    }
}

struct CustomState: View {
    @State private var text: String = ""
    let textChangeListener: TextChanger
    init(textChangeListener: TextChanger){
        self.textChangeListener = textChangeListener
        print("did init")
    }
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .onReceive(textChangeListener.textChanged){newValue in
                self.text = newValue
            }
    }
}
struct CustomStateContainer: View {
    //var state = ComplexState()
    @ObservedObject var state = ComplexState()
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Text("custom state View: ")
                CustomState(textChangeListener: state.textChangeListener)
            }
            HStack{
                Text("ordinary Text View: ")
                Text(state.text)
            }
            HStack{
                Text("text input with full state update: ")
                TextInput().environmentObject(state)
            }
            HStack{
                Text("text input with no full state update: ")
                TextInputNoUpdate().environmentObject(state)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TextInputNoUpdate: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var state: ComplexState
    var body: some View {
        TextField("input", text: Binding(   get: {self.state.text},
                                            set: {newValue in
                                                self.state.onlyPassthroughSend.toggle()
                                                self.state.text = newValue
                                                self.state.onlyPassthroughSend.toggle()
        }
        ))
    }
}

struct TextInput: View {
    @State private var text: String = ""
    @EnvironmentObject var state: ComplexState
    var body: some View {

        TextField("input", text: Binding(
            get: {self.text},
            set: {newValue in
                self.state.text = newValue
               // self.text = newValue
            }
        ))
            .onAppear(){
                self.text = self.state.text
            }.onReceive(state.textChangeListener.textChanged){newValue in
                self.text = newValue
            }
    }
}

struct CustomState_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        return CustomStateContainer()
    }
}
```

I made a manual Binding to stop broadcasting objectWillChange. But you still need to gets new value in all the places you changing this value to stay synchronized. Thats why I modified TextInput too.

Is that what you needed?

Comment: In general, I think `@State` is for internal use in Views. `@ObservedObject` is for changing data between Views. Therefore `ObservableObject` is only for classes - they are links which can be used in other views. Its like you put them in `init()` as an input parameter. What do you need to do, what you don't know exactly, what's changed? redraw wholesaled the `View`.

Comment: I think we are not talking about the same thing. I know the purpose of `@State` and `@ObservedObject`. When I understand you correctly you just tried to rebuild the `@State` using ObservableObjects. The problem I see is keeping subscriptions and States over the Redraw of the Parent View *in* an `ObservableObject`! You might be able to see what I mean, if you build a very simple App with a "Parent View", that changes its State on the Press of a Button and a child View doing the same thing, keep both States in `ObservableObjects` (with @Published) and put `prints` in `init` and `deinit`.

Comment: Your problem is about using default values of `@State` variables. When you change something (whether it another property in `@ObservedObject`, or `@EnvironmentObject` or parameter passed through `init()`) outside this view, it is to be fully destroyed and created again. Therefore your `@State` variable sets to its default value. I show you a way how to avoid destroying the View by send changes with `PassthroughSubject`. –

Comment: please see this gist: https://gist.github.com/konDeichmann/9b4e2e7947068ffd906966edddf1d093 try just replace the ContentView of a newly created SwiftUI Project and play around with the 3 Buttons. As you can see the `@State` will remain its value, while the `@ObservedObject` will always reset on the ParentsView State change.

Comment: It looks like `@State` is able to restore its value after recreating `View`, and the `@ObservedObject` is not. If you put `print()` into `CounterStateView` `init()` you will see it redrawn too, but after init complete, it copes back is old value. Try create init of state View:
    init(){
        self._counter = State(initialValue: 1)
        print("init state (with value of \(counter))")
    }

Comment: found an article about that: https://medium.com/device-blogs/all-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-state-in-swiftui-7314d0c51318

Answer (score 0):

My solution is use EnvironmentObject and don't use ObservedObject at view it's viewModel will be reset, you pass through hierarchy by

```
.environmentObject(viewModel)
```

Just init viewModel somewhere it will not be reset(example root view).